# Kettle - Append XML files content

Tags: xml, append, pentaho, kettle

How can I append two (maybe more) XML files? I search for those files using the 'Get File Names'. If more than one file is found, how can I append their content, to result in just one XML file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the "XML Join" step.  Curiously named as its not really a join (altho when you think about it i guess it is) but should do what you want.

Comment: My problem is that when I join two XML files, I get a New XML file with an initial Header and Root (from the first XML file), and then another Header and Root in the middle of the file (from the second XML file). Consequently, I can't parse the New XML file...